# Can't install managed package in scratch org

Tags: managed-package, scratch-org

I am currently working on some changes for a managed package and I've pushed the code to a scratch org for testing. However I want to test the code along side a dependent package but I can't seem to install it as it won't recognize the code inside the scratch org as the required package. How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to test an extension package against an unpackaged installation of its parent package.

You'll need to package your code, potentially in a beta managed package (I'm assuming you are using first-generation packaging), to make this possible.